# Insert String and image to mysql server by android app

Tags: android

This is my link http://amancomputers.com/mm/pma-front/services/reply.php

```
Link content->INSERT INTO incomming_message(content,date,image) VALUES('',now(),''){"login":1}
```

I want to send a text and a image in content and image respectively by using my android app. I have tried this code

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          //for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://amancomputers.com/mm/pma-front/services/reply.php");

        try {
            // Add your data

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content","name abcd"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", "AndDev is Cool!"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
   return "success";
                }
```

I have tried this code. But my problem is that a new id is created but i am unable to send a text or image on server.
 and my exception is in logcat:

```
unable to convert java.lang.string into jsonobjects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a `JSONObject` from this `String` ("12345") that is not valid json, try with a valid json string, e.g.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"whatever\":\"12345\"}");
```

or just an empty object

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
```

Comment: can i do this  nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", jsonObject));

Comment: @user3764509 I don't think so, the value must be a string. In your case would be .. "content",jsonObject.toString())); The point is, what do you need a JSONObject for?

Comment: my exception is 06-22 05:35:04.140: E/Fail 3(7733): org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: @user3764509 this means that you're trying to parse a non-json string as json, it's the same problem I addressed in my answer. how are you initializing the JSONObject?

Comment: thanx for your support. i have solved problem. My problem was i was giving wrong value to namevaluepair my parameter name on sever was get message and i was giving content